# Accessing Views from one MVC project to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Newish to MVC so please forgive me if i am overlooking a major concept.

Ive simplified my projects to two basic projects to see what concept im missing. I have two MVC projects setup one called "Path" the other is "Guru". Path being the starting project i am able to access the route to Guru's Controller "Shine" however when it attempts to return the view it is unable to find the view.

I then copied the views folder from Guru to Path and the program works well i am able to call the controller from Guru and in turn it appears to use Paths view folder. My question is how can i setup some sort of routing to get to the views folder in Guru?

I had attempted a custom view engine but im unsure of how to tell said engine to reach into Guru instead of "Path". Making copies of every view into the Path project seems very impractical and cant be the best approach.

It seems with the code below i am simply telling the program to look in the same exact place as it was already currently looking.

```
public class GuruViewEngine : VirtualPathProviderViewEngine
{
    public GuruViewEngine()
    {
        // Define the location of the View file
        this.ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    { "~/Views/Shine/{1}/{0}", "~/Views/Shared/{0}" };

        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[]
    { "~/Views/{1}/{0}", "~/Views/Shared/{0}" };
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        var physicalpath = controllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(partialPath);
        return new GuruView(physicalpath);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var physicalpath = controllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(viewPath);
        return new GuruView(physicalpath);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to give exact path of the view folder. I am unable to see Guru there

Comment: Are you saying this line ~/Views/Shine/{1}/{0}, needs to be Guru/Views/Shine/{1}/{0} because i gave this a try but was unable to access the folder still yet

Comment: Can you explain why you have two projects instead of one with necessary routing in it?

Comment: ssnith i may be missing something concept wise because i have a route setup in Path as below however it still throws an error that "The view 'NewPage' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations "            

routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Shine",
                            url: "Shine/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Shine", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                            );

Answer (score 0):

To get your View file from your assembly (other projects too), you can use below code.  You need to set your view's content type as Embedded Resource.

```
 public class AssemblyVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        private readonly Assembly assembly;
        private readonly IEnumerable<VirtualPathProvider> providers;

        public AssemblyVirtualPathProvider(Assembly assembly)
        {
            var engines = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<VirtualPathProviderViewEngine>().ToList();

           this.providers = engines.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("VirtualPathProvider", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(x, null) as VirtualPathProvider).Distinct().ToList();
           this.assembly = assembly;
       }

       public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(String virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
       {
           if (this.FindFileByPath(this.CorrectFilePath(virtualPath)) != null)
           {
               return (new AssemblyCacheDependency(assembly));
           }
           else
           {
               return (base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart));
           }
       }

       public override Boolean FileExists(String virtualPath)
       {
           foreach (var provider in this.providers)
           {
               if (provider.FileExists(virtualPath) == true)
               {
                   return (true);
               }
           }

           var exists = this.FindFileByPath(this.CorrectFilePath(virtualPath)) != null;

           return (exists);
       }

       public override VirtualFile GetFile(String virtualPath)
       {
           var resource = null as Stream;

           foreach (var provider in this.providers)
           {
               var file = provider.GetFile(virtualPath);

               if (file != null)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       resource = file.Open();
                       return (file);
                   }
                   catch
                   {
                   }
               }
           }

           var resourceName = this.FindFileByPath(this.CorrectFilePath(virtualPath));

           return (new AssemblyVirtualFile(virtualPath, this.assembly, resourceName));
       }

       protected String FindFileByPath(String virtualPath)
       {
           var resourceNames = this.assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

           return (resourceNames.SingleOrDefault(r => r.EndsWith(virtualPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true));
       }

       protected String CorrectFilePath(String virtualPath)
       {
           return (virtualPath.Replace("~", String.Empty).Replace('/', '.'));
       }
   }

   public class AssemblyVirtualFile : VirtualFile
   {
       private readonly Assembly assembly;
       private readonly String resourceName;

       public AssemblyVirtualFile(String virtualPath, Assembly assembly, String resourceName) : base(virtualPath)
       {
           this.assembly = assembly;
           this.resourceName = resourceName;
       }

       public override Stream Open()
       {
           return (this.assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(this.resourceName));
       }
   }

   public class AssemblyCacheDependency : CacheDependency
   {
       private readonly Assembly assembly;

      public AssemblyCacheDependency(Assembly assembly)
      {
          this.assembly = assembly;
          this.SetUtcLastModified(File.GetCreationTimeUtc(assembly.Location));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Apologies for my lack of knowledge here but i am having trouble implementing this very likely to me using it incorrectly. Would i use this with the view engine to translate the file paths? Can you provide some details?

Comment: It will pick you views from your assembly's dll.